# Extract single database from --alldatabase.sql.gz

Tags: mysql, database, dump

I have a dump file of sql db.Which contain 100+db i want to extract single database from "dump_db_19.sql.gz" like test_db_1.sql 
please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
mysql -u <user> -p --one-database test_db_1  < alldatabases.sql
```